# HttpResponseMessage missing headers while using HttpClient but fiddler finds it

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am making a simple `HttpClient` call like this:

```
Uri basePath = new Uri("https://my-host.com/");
string path = "api/my-path";

using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = basePath;

    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(path);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        response.Headers.Select(header => header.Key).Dump();
    }
}
```

I am looking for a custom auth-header on the response but it is missing when I iterate over `Headers` collection.

However, same Http request caught by `Fiddler` shows the header.
If I make same request on `Postman` or any browser, I see the header.

Wondering what am I missing here.

[Update]

Raw Headers captured on `Fiddler` by executing same code above:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Location: <redacted>
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
WWW-Authenticate-Test: <redacted>
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: <redacted>
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Date: Sat, 11 Nov 2017 23:15:19 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Headers printed by above code:

```
Pragma 
Strict-Transport-Security 
X-Content-Type-Options 
X-Frame-Options 
x-ms-request-id 
Cache-Control 
P3P 
Set-Cookie 
Server 
X-Powered-By 
Date
```

I would like to capture the header `WWW-Authenticate-Test` which is somehow filtered out while it goes through the `HttpClient` magic.

Comment: After more research, I realized `HttpClient` strips auth headers from the response whenever there is a redirect (for security). So the solution seem to be fixing the server to return 200 instead of 302/301

Answer (score 7):

It's probably a [content header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.headers(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
response.Content.Headers.Select(header => header.Key).Dump();
```

Comment: No, the response has no body and I have verified the content header.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the headers you see in Fiddler - we will be able to create reproductions then...